# How to query model by property which is object of arrays in loopback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I have a requirement to query an object that looks like below

```
video: {
id: "xxxxxx",
title: "xxxxxx",
categories: [
   {id: "xxxxxx", title: "xxxxxxx" },
   {id: "xxxxxx", title: "xxxxxxx" },
   {id: "xxxxxx", title: "xxxxxxx" },
   ]

}
```

I am required to return all videos that have title equal to some regex or have categories whose title is equal to that regex. Simply match regex with the title of the video and match title of the categories of that video, if a match is true then return that video with all its categories included.

**Note:** "categories" is a separate model included in "video" model

**Update**: I have modified object structure

Comment: That's not a valid structure. Also please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service.The objective here is to help you fix **your code**

Comment: the structure of categories is wrong, try `categories: {
  vid1: [id: "xxxxxx", title: "xxxxxxx" ],
  vid2 :[id: "xxxxxx", title: "xxxxxxx" ],
  vid3 :[id: "xxxxxx", title: "xxxxxxx" ]
   }` can you please add more informations ?

Comment: yes you are right, i have modified my object structure now

Comment: @charlietfl I am really sorry, I have posted wrong code by mistake. I posted this after a lot of trying and reading loopback docs, but nothing is working for me.